# Making text respond to viewport? Removing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In the website I'm currently building, I have a sidebar nav which fills the left 10% of the window, and a content which fills the other 90% to the right of that.

When I snap the window to the left or right of the screen (as many users may) the content text overflows and creates a horizontal scroll bar, which in this situation is disgusting.

Now, how would I go about making the text within the content respond to the viewport? I know there's a simple solution that im missing.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>About</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sintony' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- /CSS -->


  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="side-footer">
        <p><a href="mailto:business@darmisdigitaldesigns.net?subject=Website">Contact Webmaster</a><br />&copy; DDD 2012-2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="content-wrap">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <hr>
        <p> Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

ALL CSS:

```
    body {
    font: 16px/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #EEE;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    clear: right;
}

/***********/
/* Sidebar */
/***********/

#sidebar {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(40,40,40);
    /*border-right: 1px solid rgb(30,30,30);*/
    box-shadow: -2px 0 2px -2px #222;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#sidebar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Sintony', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#sidebar ul li:first-child a:hover, #sidebar ul li:first-child a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

#sidebar ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover, #sidebar ul li:nth-child(2) a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

#sidebar ul li:last-child a:hover, #sidebar ul li:last-child a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

#side-footer {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 8px;
}

#sidebar #side-footer  p{
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.5em;
}

#sidebar #side-footer  a {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    color: #FFF;
}

/***************/
/* END Sidebar */
/***************/

#content {
    width: 85.5%;
    height: 95%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    position: absolute;
}

#content-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
}

#content p {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-indent: 1.5625em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

#content h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-sarif;
    text-indent: 1.5625em;
    line-height: 0.3125em;
}

#content hr {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: So do you just want to remove the scrollbar and keep the container widths the same? Or do you want the container widths to increase in size as the screen size shrinks?

Comment: How do you know enough to use the *responsive-design* tag but fail to explore what responsive design actually involves?

Comment: I simply want the text to respond to the width of the window by, instead of creating the scroll bar, going down the height of the window (if that makes sense). If container heights need to be adjusted to accomplish this, that's fine. Whatever works.

Comment: Your content-wrap is explicity set to 960px so of course you get scrollbars when the window is narrower than that.

Comment: Cimmanon, I'm not here for your toxicity, I'm here to figure out what I'm doing wrong. If you would like to help, great. But if you're here to flame, I'm not interested.

Comment: Wow, thank you SpliFF. I knew it was something stupid. I felt like an idiot for not seeing it. Thank you for your help though. I'll pay more attention in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:  I would avoid using percentages as widths because browser windows do change.  I would switch to using a responsive design.  The only reason I did suggest responsive design is because you tagged your post as responsive design, so I am assuming you want to move to that route.

The easier the design, the easier the setup, but it will take more effort to set up a responsive design than a regular css stylesheet.  Here are some tips and an example of a responsive template I built.

---

Okay, what I do is set up multiple stylesheets and use css to define the screen sizes.  Here are some examples as modifying your code for a responsive design will take entirely too long.  Getting use to working with responsive sites takes a little while because there is more to modify and set up and you really have to find what works for you...but this is what worked for me.

mainstylesheet.css
- This stylesheet is for content tht doesn't really get effected by responsive design.  This can be anything from colors for colorschemes, background colors, maybe even column colors if they don't want them to get modified.  This gets set up using plain css with no responsive modifiers

After your main stylesheet is set up, you can then set up your responsive stylesheets which are the ones that change depending on size of screen/browser window.  Each stylesheet has to be included on every page that you want to use a responsive design in.  This can all be combined into 1 giant stylesheet, but I find it easier to manage when things are split up.  At the top of each one, you will add a variant of the following lines

Full:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 960px) {
```

Condensed

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 744px)
and (max-width : 959px) {
```

Scalable

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 743px)
and (min-width : 481px) {
```

Mobile

```
@media 
only screen and (max-width : 480px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
```

(Don't forget to end each stylesheet with an extra } as well to close off the @media tag.)

Each of my stylesheets also has a hidden div class similar to the following:

```
.hidecontent_mobile { display: none !important;}
```

Same with scalable, condensed, and full as I add those classes in for content I don't want to display in each different version.

So, to explain how to set this up using your code...

1) Lets say you want your sidebar to change in every version as far as size goes, but you want it to disappear in mobile version.  What you would do is, for each stylesheet, you would add `#sidebar { width: *width*; }` and then to your html you would add  `<div id="sidebar" class="hidecontent_mobile">`  And once you finish with everything, your sidebar will adjust based on width of screen and will disappear when on mobile version.

Some of this code may have to be altered to fit your needs.  I yanked it out of an existing project I am working on to give you an example.

Let me know if you have any further questions regarding this and I will try to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the width of the page in pixels. This is needed to get your thing working.

For example, I would have used this:

`body { 
max-width: 980px; 
width: 100%;}`

`#sidebar {
width: 90%;
}`

Of course it's nice to use`media queries` and an `external stylesheet`, as stated above, but that means you are loading in multiple stylesheets, which makes your site slower. That is not good for the `SEO` of the website, because `Google` does not like that.